# How to show Facebook business manager account link with facebook app in facebook app Advance setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook app.

I have facebook business manager account.

I have added facebook app to facebook business manager account.

Now, When I visit my facebook app settings, its not showing me there 
like "ABC app is connected with ABC business account".

Do I missed any setting? OR what is the process of it?

like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer.

The facebook app must be in live status.

My app was In Development status so its not showing Business manager account there.